# Lowering the saving time when asynchronously loading records into database using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using **[MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)** as an interface to the default **CoreData** interface. 
In this app I am loading two wordlists(encyclopaedias) into the database the first time a user starts the application.

Here is the snippet of the method performing the load/save. It is called from my Application Delegate, within

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (![defaults boolForKey:@"HasInitiatedWordlists"]) {

    Dictionary *dictionary = [Dictionary MR_createEntity];
    dictionary.language = @"English";

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brittish_wordlist" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *stringArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];

    // ALL ENGLISH WORDS //
    for(NSString *string in stringArray)
    {
        Word *w = [Word MR_createEntity];
        w.dictionary =dictionary;
        w.word = string;
    }

    dictionary = [Dictionary MR_createEntity];
    dictionary.language = @"Swedish";

    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"swedish_wordlist" ofType:@"txt"];
    content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    stringArray = [content componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];

    // ALL SWEDISH WORDS //
    for(NSString *string in stringArray)
    {
        Word *w = [Word MR_createEntity];
        w.dictionary =dictionary;
        w.word = string;
    }


    // SAVING TO PERSISTENT STORE ASYNCHRONOUSLY
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:(MRSaveCompletionHandler)^{
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"HasInitiatedWordlists"];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }];


} else {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The saving part, found last in the above code, takes a really long time (like 1 minute on device and 20 sec on the simulator).

The two wordlists consists of 221599 words and 109583 words respectively. 
I know thats a lot of words, but is 1 minute really reasonable? Is there something else that I am missing?

How can I improve this loading time, so that the user experience won't have to suffer?

Note: The loading time is not significantly lower if I try to perform the saving synchronously

Comment: Why don't you distribute the app with a pre-populated sqlite data store file to use as the store (or as a seed DB)?

Comment: That thought has occurred to me to. And I will probably do it :) But my question still remains. Is this reasonable?

Comment: It's a lot of items. Reasonable has nothing to do with it. You can use the core data instrument to profile performance and see what takes the longest, then you can try batch saving, and splitting the load across multiple threads...